# What is the default username and password of phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have downloaded the latest version of phpmyadmin. but now I cannot login to phpmyadmin. What is the default username and password of it?
While I tried username and password as root and blank then it say **#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server**

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL server is running? Can you connect via the command line client (`mysql -u root -p` on a *nix-like command line or using the corresponding program from the Windows Start Menu)? You're correct that by default the username is root with a blank password.

Answer (score 10):

You can check your username and password by using this command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Find the lines below:

```
dbc_dbuser='yyy'
dbc_dbpass='zzz'
```

yyy is username and zzz is your password.

Answer (score 0):

Edit phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Note:if you installed fresh then, config.inc.php may not exist. You need to rename / copy config.sample.inc.php and then change the relevant line.

Answer (score 0):

The default username of phpMyAdmin is "root" and the password is "root" ;)

Comment: Working ! The default username of phpMyAdmin in MAMP and password is 'root'

Answer (score 0):

the username is root and password is your sql's password, but you'd better make sure you don't stop the remote login with root in your sql server .

Answer (score -1):

The default username of phpMyAdmin is "root". and the password is "admin"

Comment: Cannot login. It say same. ***

> #2002 cannot login to phpmyadmin.

***